# Python 3.3 + Django 1.6 + Connector/Python Django Backend + South

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-south

I want to use this set: Ubuntu 12.04 + Python 3.3 + Django 1.6 + MySQL 5.5;

For support MySQL i used "Connector/Python Django Backend" ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html)).

My settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'test',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

This is work.

But yet i want to use "South". I successfully installed "South".

```
pip install south==0.8.4

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
)
```

Here's what happened

```
python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1512, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from south.management.commands.syncdb import Command as SyncCommand
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 19, in <module>
    from south.db import dbs
  File "/home/mikhail/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/db/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    db = dbs[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
KeyError: 'default'
```

**What to do?**

Comment: Can you try it with using the django mysql engine? django.db.backends.mysql

Comment: "At the time of writing, the latest release of MySQLdb (1.2.4) doesn’t support Python 3. In order to use MySQL under Python 3, you’ll have to install an unofficial fork, such as MySQL-for-Python-3.". This is official manual of Django 1.6. I have not tried Mysql backend used.

Answer (score 3):

To support the MySQL need to use MySQL-for-Python-3 ([link](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3))

Install:

```
$ tar xfz MySQL-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
$ cd MySQL-python-1.2.1
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Next on the official Django manual.